# Finding dp/dt differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the question:

The penguin population on an Alaskan island p, t years after they were introduced is modelled by the equation:

[image]

Find dp/dt.

I am not sure how to approach this question but I do know that I have to use the product rule.

I know I have to differentiate but I do not know which terms should be U and V.

Comment: What products do you have to differentiate?

Comment: Also, please don't introduce penguins to Alaska.  Really bad idea.  In less than $100$ years you'll have a trillion of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the product rule, $$\frac {\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(100e^{t/4})=100\frac {\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(e^{t/4})=25e^{t/4}$$
If anything, you have to use the chain rule. Set $f(t)=e^t$ and $g(t)=\frac t4$ and compute $f(g(t))'=f'(g(t))g'(t)$

Comment: Actually you do use the product rule but you may not think about it, because in this case the $\frac{d(100)}{dt} = 0$ which makes the other term disappear.

Comment: @mathreadler You could see it that way, but I rather see it as the linearity of the derivative